# How to produce one binary with a different name than the project name?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have the project `MyApp.dproj` and I want to produce the app **`MyName.exe`** (or on ios for example `MyName.ipa` that will contain `MyName.app`). Is it possible **without renaming the MyApp.dproj**

Comment: If you don't want to rename the project you can still rename the exe (or whatever is produced) after compile.

Comment: Look into using a post-build event - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Creating_Build_Events

Comment: I would rather make a copy with the other name. Otherwise you can not debug your app! Or you rename the app only when you build the release version.

Comment: You better change or copy the project to a new name or you will have trouble when trying to make Android and IOS apps.